# Jackson: Keep references to keys in map values when deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON with a map from user IDs to user details:

```
{
    "users": {
        "john": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" },
        "mark": { "firstName": "Mark", "lastName": "Smith" }
    }
}
```

and I'm using the following code to deserialize the JSON into a Java objects:

```
class User {
    public String userID;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}

public class Users {
    public Map<String, User> users;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Reader source = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.json"));
        Users all = mapper.readValue(source, Users.class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

After the deserialization, I want the field `User.userID` to be set to the corresponding key in the `users` map.

For example `all.users.get("john").userID` should be `"john"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom deserializer for User object and use this for the Map.  Here's a full example:

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Data data = mapper.readValue("{\"users\": {\"John\": {\"id\": 20}, \"Pete\": {\"id\": 30}}}", Data.class);

    assertEquals(20, data.users.get("John").id);
    assertEquals(30, data.users.get("Pete").id);
    assertEquals("John", data.users.get("John").name);
    assertEquals("Pete", data.users.get("Pete").name);
}

public static class Data {
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = Deser.class)
    public Map<String, User> users;
}

public static class User {
    public String name;
    public int id;
}

public static class Deser extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String name = ctxt.getParser().getCurrentName();

        User user = p.readValueAs(User.class);

        user.name = name;  // This copies the key name to the user object

        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution for the problem is to implement a custom deserializer for the class in which you need the map key (see [john16384's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766551/1523648)). This is however cumbersome if you have multiple maps with different value types in your JSON because you'd need one deserializer per type.

In this case, there is a better solution: I would create a custom `@JsonMapKey` annotation to mark the target properties for the map keys, and then register a generic custom deserializer that processes all occurrences of the annotation. These are the parts you need for this:

Custom `@JsonMapKey` annotation:

```
/**
 * Annotation used to indicate that the annotated property shall be deserialized to the map key of
 * the current object. Requires that the object is a deserialized map value.
 * 
 * Note: This annotation is not a standard Jackson annotation. It will only work if this is
 * explicitly enabled in the {@link ObjectMapper}.
 */
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JsonMapKey {

}
```

Custom deserializer that processes the `@JsonMapKey` annotations:

```
public class JsonMapKeyDeserializer extends DelegatingDeserializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BeanDescription beanDescription;

    public JsonMapKeyDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> delegate, BeanDescription beanDescription) {
        super(delegate);
        this.beanDescription = beanDescription;
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatingInstance(JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatee) {
        return new JsonMapKeyDeserializer(newDelegatee, beanDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String mapKey = p.getCurrentName();
        Object deserializedObject = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        // set map key on all fields annotated with @JsonMapKey
        for (BeanPropertyDefinition beanProperty : beanDescription.findProperties()) {
            AnnotatedField field = beanProperty.getField();
            if (field != null && field.getAnnotation(JsonMapKey.class) != null) {
                field.setValue(deserializedObject, mapKey);
            }
        }
        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

Registration of the custom deserializer in the `ObjectMapper`:

```
private static void registerJsonMapKeyAnnotation(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, 
                BeanDescription beanDescription, JsonDeserializer<?> originalDeserializer) {
            return new JsonMapKeyDeserializer(originalDeserializer, beanDescription);
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
}
```

---

Then you only need to annotate the field to be used for the map key...

```
class User {
    @JsonMapKey
    public String userID;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

... and deserialize your JSON with the prepared `ObjectMapper`:

```
Users all = registerJsonMapKeyAnnotation(new ObjectMapper()).readValue(source, Users.class);
```

Comment: I also filed a [feature request](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2321) to have Jackson support `@JsonMapKey` or a similar annotation out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

First Create the `ObjectMapper` `class` object than `configure` it.

Try following one.

**Sample Code**

```
Map<K, V> map;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
map = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<Map<K, V>>() {});
```

than you can get the value using `Map`.

Comment: This does not answer the question